# Show that in a group $G$ there is exactly one element $g$ for which $g^2 = g$?

Tags: group-theory, idempotents

> Show that in a group $G$ there is exactly one element $g$ for which $g^2 = g$?

What are they essentially asking here? This seems to be a bit general question since its considering all sets that form groups? For the group $(\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ this would correspond to $1^2=1=e$? Any elaboration/hints on how to show this would be welcome...

Comment: The "cancellation law" in a group says that $ax=bx$ implies $a=b$. So $g^2=g$ gives $g=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking you to show that, no matter the element $g$ in your group $G$, if $g^2=g$, then $g=e$ (since $e^2=e$). So let $g\in G$ such that $g^2=g$. Multiply on, say, the left, by $g^{-1}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
e&=g^{-1}g\\
&=g^{-1}g^2\\
&=(g^{-1}g)g\\
&=eg\\
&=g.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Would this hold for larger powers of $g$?

Comment: You're welcome, @Dan. No, it doesn't hold for higher powers, since, for example, if $g^3=g$ and $h^3=h$, then $g^2=e=h^2$, from which it doesn't follow that $g=h$; consider the free product $$\Bbb Z_2\ast\Bbb Z_2\cong\langle g,h\mid g^2, h^2\rangle.$$ This group is a counterexample.

Comment: ... or more simply $(\mathbb{R}^*, .)$ where $(-1)^2=1=1^2$ but $1 \neq -1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$g^2=g \Longrightarrow g^{-1}(g^2)=g^{-1}g \Longrightarrow g=e$$

Answer (score 1):

*A variant*: the simplification rule is valid in groups, so
$$g^2(=gg)=g(=ge)\implies g=e.$$